# My Tflite model works perfectly in jupyter notebook. However shows me the wrong output when I try to run it in Android studio

Tags: python, java, android, tensorflow

So I created my custom model for disease recognition based on the symptoms entered by the patient. And it works perfectly on python, However after I converted it to tflite and ran it on android studio, It gives me wrong predictions irrespective of the input values.
I've tested the tflite model on python and it's working fine.

Following code shows how I converted my model to tflite:-

```
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
saved_model= load_model('Disease-predictor_ANN.h5')

    #Convert to tflite model
from tensorflow import lite 
converter= lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(saved_model)
tflite_model= converter.convert()

#Save the model
with open('dpredictor.tflite','wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

The following code shows my activity file where I have implemented the tflite model in android studio:-

```
package com.example.prototype_idoc;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBufferFloat;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class diseaseDiagnosis extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MultiAutoCompleteTextView multiAutoCompleteTextView;
    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;

    public diseaseDiagnosis() throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_disease_diagnosis);

        MapdatabaseHelper mapdatabaseHelper= new MapdatabaseHelper(this);
        try {
            mapdatabaseHelper.createDatabase();
            mapdatabaseHelper.openDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<String> symptomList= (ArrayList<String>) mapdatabaseHelper.getEverySymptom(this);
        ArrayList<String> diseaseList= (ArrayList<String>) mapdatabaseHelper.getEveryDisease(this);
        String[] symptoms= symptomList.toArray(new String[symptomList.size()]);
        String[] diseases= diseaseList.toArray(new String[diseaseList.size()]);
        mapdatabaseHelper.close();
        multiAutoCompleteTextView= findViewById(R.id.multiAutoView);
        button= findViewById(R.id.checkDisease);
        textView= findViewById(R.id.diseaseName);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,symptoms);
        multiAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        multiAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
        multiAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                float[] model_input= new float[132];
                Arrays.fill(model_input, new Float(0));
                String itemsSelected= multiAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();
                int startIndex=0;
                for(int i=0;i<itemsSelected.length();i++){
                    if(itemsSelected.charAt(i)==','){
                        String s=itemsSelected.substring(startIndex,i);
                        int currIndex=symptomList.indexOf(s);
                        Log.v("CURR INDEX:",s+ ":"+currIndex);
                        model_input[currIndex]= 1.0F;
                        startIndex=i+2;
                    }
                }

                Context context = null;
                try {
                    context = createPackageContext("com.example.prototype_idoc", 0);
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
                Interpreter interpreter=null;
                try {
                   interpreter= new Interpreter(loadModelFile(assetManager,"dpredictor.tflite"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ByteBuffer inputBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(132*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
                inputBuffer.rewind();
                for(int i=0;i<model_input.length;i++){
                    inputBuffer.putFloat(model_input[i]);
                }
                float[] outputArray= new float[41];
                TensorBuffer outputBuffer= TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1,41},DataType.FLOAT32);
                interpreter.run(inputBuffer,outputBuffer.getBuffer());
                outputArray= outputBuffer.getFloatArray();
//

                int modelOutputIndex= 0;
                float maxNum= outputArray[0];
                for(int i=0;i<outputArray.length;i++){
                    if(maxNum>outputArray[i]){
                        modelOutputIndex=i;
                        maxNum=outputArray[i];
                    }
                }
                Log.v("TAG:", "onClick: "+ outputArray[15] );
                Log.v("TAG:", "onClick: "+ outputArray[25] );
                textView.setText(diseases[modelOutputIndex]);
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });



    }


    private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(AssetManager assetManager, String modelPath) throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(modelPath);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! There are 2 possible issues: conversion-related and deployment-related. I would like to suggest try to inference your tflite model in python prior to deployment. Check [how](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python) and let us know is it work as expected.

Comment: Yes I've switched up the code and I have used an interpreter instead of the code generated by android studio from the tflite model and now the output changes however it's the wrong output and I tested my tflite model in python and it's working fine

Comment: I see you are using tensorbuffer for output while input is managed manually. Try to setup tensorbuffer for input as well, manual setup may be tricky so you can finish up with wrong data for input. Use `inputBuffer=TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[] {%input_shape%}, DataType.FLOAT32); inputBuffer.loadArray(%data_flat_array%)`

Comment: Yeah Thank you so much it's working now. Appreciate it